# p4 reconcile returns error

Tags: perforce

When running "p4 reconcile" command.

It returns following error:

*Client doesn't have necessary support for reconcile.*

What it means? p4v can do reconcile on the same PC.

Comment: Is your p4 client actually up to date?

Comment: Rev. P4/NTX86/2007.2/122958 (2007/05/22).

Comment: Way too old. You need 2012.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P4 reconcile requires at least version 2012.1.

[Taken from the Perforce Blog:](http://www.perforce.com/blog/120126/new-20121-p4reconcile-p4status)

The 2012.1 release of Perforce is just about to be released for beta. It's loaded with great new features. One is the p4 reconcile command, with its fraternal twin, p4 status.

Comment: Can you provide links to this info?

Comment: Updated answer with an appropriate link + quote.